# Is there a way to manage github projects from the cli?

Tags: github, command-line-interface

I'd like to list projects and issues under projects on github from the cli.  I don't see any direct commands like `gh project list` or any available extensions, or even anyone else asking about this capability.  Does anyone know how to do this or why it would be an inherently goofy thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

Of course 5m after posting a question I see [using-the-api-to-manage-projects](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/trying-out-the-new-projects-experience/using-the-api-to-manage-projects)!  It is just less convenient than other cli functions.